Delete data from child tables with Stored Procedure
I have a schema named new_schema with a table result. This table has many child tables with inheritance, named like result_23, result_45, etc.
I have 3500 millions of rows and the database coming slow. One row has a timestamp field named new_date. This start from '2022-01-01'. I want to delete all rows before: 2023-11-01.
Deleting from the parent table takes too long. I try to delete from child tables directly in a SP, executed with the postgres superuser. If something happens, I can continue the work later.
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION new_schema.delete_old_rows()

RETURNS TABLE (child_table text)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE
    child_table text;
    sql_query text;
BEGIN
    FOR child_table IN
        SELECT table_name
        FROM information_schema.tables
        WHERE table_schema = 'new_schema'
        AND table_name LIKE 'result_%'
    loop
        sql_query := 'DELETE FROM new_schema.' || child_table || ' WHERE new_date < ''2023-11-01'';';
        EXECUTE consulta_sql;
        RAISE NOTICE 'Data deleted in table: %', child_table;
    END LOOP;
END
$function$;

I DELETE from each child table in a loop, and it seems to work (though it takes long for big tables). But when I check with a SELECT, data from 2022 is still there.
When printing the query string, the DELETE looks perfect:

CONTEXT:  SQL statement "DELETE FROM new_schema.result_26
WHERE new_date < '2023-11-01';"

I tried to apply COMMIT after each DELETE, but that does not work.

I don't know if you were just translating for our benefit, but your code uses new_date while the printout is showing fecha. Let me suggest something that may speed your program up. Besides whatever partition scheme you are using now, also partition the table by dates (say, by month). In that case, you can detach and drop entire tables, which is very fast, instead of deleting records, which is slow.

Thanks, yes it was my mistake in posting, because "fecha" is the real name of column and when i paste it, i forgot change the name of that. But now i correct the post. So that is not the problem. Thanks again.

Why are you returning a TABLE? Looks to me as if you return void. I think returning NULL may cause a problem.

Maybe could be, i recycle other old SP. But i thought it doesn't care, because the important is the EXECUTE in the loop. Really i don't know it could be the problem. What i must return? void?

A FUNCTION is not a PROCEDURE. In a procedure you can commit, change your code to a procedure and add the commit. Use CALL to invoke the procedure.

You want a PROCEDURE instead of a FUNCTION. There you can issue COMMIT. See:

How to force COMMIT inside function so other sessions can see updated row?
Does a procedure run in a transaction in PostgreSQL?

Could work like this:
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE new_schema.delete_old_rows()  -- !!!
  -- no RETURNS clause  -- !!!
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _child text;
   _row_ct int;
BEGIN
   FOR _child IN
      SELECT quote_ident(table_name)  -- !!!
      FROM   information_schema.tables
      WHERE  table_schema = 'new_schema'
      AND    table_name LIKE 'result_%'
   LOOP
      EXECUTE 'DELETE FROM new_schema.' || _child || ' WHERE new_date < ''2023-11-01''';      
      GET DIAGNOSTICS _row_ct = ROW_COUNT;
      COMMIT;  -- !!!
      RAISE NOTICE '% rows deleted from table: %', _row_ct, _child;
   END LOOP;
END
$func$;

Execute with CALL (important!):
CALL new_schema.delete_old_rows();

Also note that your original was open to SQL injection attacks. Identifiers have to be treated as user input in dynamic SQL. See:

Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter
Define table and column names as arguments in a plpgsql function?

And you confused variable names: consulta_sql vs. sql_query. I simplified.
While being at it, I added a row count (practically for free). See:

Count rows affected by DELETE
Variables for identifiers inside IF EXISTS in a plpgsql function


Thanks Erwin for your time. First of all, the function doesn't return any error, that line i get from a error typing (or for put commit, i don't remember). I took this complete line like showing what sql statement was constructed and executing.
Thanks for clarification about commit inside a procedure, for me a procedure doesn't return and function return something, for that i recycle that old function and modify this. I'll change to procedure and try with your code.
I never use 'call' for execute, always use with select, i'll try this too.

About: consulta_sql and sql_query, was my typing mistake, because i change the original code.
Thanks again for you advices, i'll try change it and tell you how works.

@Alvaro: CALL executes a procedure, that's not optional. Also, a procedure with transaction control statements cannot be wrapped in an outer transaction. Follow the links I provided. Also, if your function did not return any error, the deletes would have been committed.

Thank you so much, it work perfectly, only i have to put the space between "simple quote" and "where". But now is deleting it. Again thanks Erwin!
